# Importing 50GB SQL freezing up or won't complete

Tags: mysql

I run the following to export the table via mysqldump:

> mysqldump -h localhost --user=user --password=password mydatabase
> my50gbtable --hex-blob --single-transaction --quick
> --max_allowed_packet=999M --compress > my50gbtable.sql

I have a 4GB ram virtual machine on my local machine that I run the insert on.

**I've tried the following:**

*HeidiSQL > Run SQL File*

- The results are that there are that it completes, but millions of records are missing. I see lots of "mysql has gone away" style errors which tells me that HeidiSQL has had to reconnect - perhaps the cause of missing data.

*I've followed these steps also: https://manios.org/2013/03/19/import-a-large-sql-dump-file-to-a-mysql-database-from-command-line*

- The results are that it will freeze and never complete with an eventual "mysql has gone away" style error.

*I've also tried changing some settings such as these:*

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
[mysqld]
innodb_doublewrite = 0
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 256M
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_write_io_threads = 16
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
net_read_timeout = 3000
net_write_timeout = 3000
interactive_timeout = 2147483
wait_timeout = 2147483
max_allowed_packet = 1073741824
```

*And then importing...*

> mysql --max_allowed_packet=1G --default-character-set=utf8 --user=user
> --password=password mydatabase < my50gbtable.sql

- This results in the same mysql has gone away errors.

**What I haven't tried:**

- [BigDump](https://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/) - because I need to re-export my table without extended inserts, and ideally I want to avoid needing to do that!

**Does anyone know what the issue MIGHT be (to cause mysql has gone away error, or records to not get inserted when importing via heidisql)?**

- Not enough memory/CPU? (I have no idea what requirements a system would need to import a large sql file)
- Is there data corruption potentially? (It doesn't appear like it, as the table is in-use live and has had no noted issues occur)
- Poor mysql config. settings?

Comment: I've done multiple imports with large data before and my config is somewhat similar to yours except for the **timeouts** settings. Try removing all that timeout settings in my.cnf, save it, restart the service and try importing again.. see if that could help

Comment: I removed all the timeout settings and re-tried. Unfortunately the import fails the same way with "Lost connection ot MySQL server during query" error :(

Comment: Maybe you can refer this : https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/83385/191579 .. I got my answer somewhere there.. and additionally in my current mysql settings includes these `key_buffer_size=2G
max_connections=1000
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_limit=256K
query_cache_min_res_unit=2k
query_cache_size=200M
sort_buffer_size=16M
read_buffer_size=16M
read_rnd_buffer_size=16M
skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve`

Comment: Thanks tcadidot0 I also read that one and tried those settings. I've just now tried increasing memory and the query got further before failing, so I guess I'll need to look at fixing memory if this is in fact a memory issue. I'm going to try adding swap for starters.